# some module doesn't work with pyw. (But It work with py)

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to check internet speed periodically, using speedtest-cli.
You can find this module here https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli and can install with pip like this.

`pip install speedtest-cli`

Also I want do this job as background job, So I made the pyw file. But When I tried to run it as pyw, importing speedtest, It didn't work. Of course I might be able to do this with other codes or other module. But I wonder why speedtest don't work with pyw.

If you can not reproduce the same problem with below code, please let me know. That means my environment has some problems.

```
import speedtest
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("test windows")
```

Comment: Please elaborate "it didn't work". [Ask]